# Compile JADE with multiple object files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

I am creating some static html files with jade:

```
jade index.jade --obj file1.json --out build/
```

And this works fine. But as soon as I am trying to enter another file as obj:

```
jade index.jade --obj file1.json, file2.json --out build/
```

or

```
jade index.jade --obj {file1,file2}.json --out build/
```

or

```
jade index.jade --obj file1.json --obj file2.json --out build/
```

It is not working anymore:

```
undefined:1
(./src/file1.json)
 ^

 SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at parseObj (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/bin/jade.js:78:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/bin/jade.js:66:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:972:3
```

Otherwise, when I am trying to use a wildcard:

```
jade index.jade --obj *.json --out build/
```

only one file can get rendered in the views.

I could not find any information in the offical [docs](http://jade-lang.com/command-line/). So simple question:

**How can I include multiple JSON files when compiling jade?**

Comment: if you check jade.js you would see that it expects one json file or json string, so if you want it to accept multiple files you can overwrite function called parseObj to read multiple files or you need to merge your json files into single file.